# How to limit the usage of types converter to a specific controller in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, converters

When dealing with request parameters, path variables or form fields in Spring MVC I have to handle `typeMismatch` errors. They occur just before the validation even begins, which can be irritating at times. Let's say I have an `Integer` parameter annotated with standard validation constraint, sort of: `@Min(value = 0, message = "Only non-negative integer values can be accepted")`. Then, I could create a simple String to Integer converter to suppresses `NumberFormatException` while setting all unparsable String values to -1, so that they could be further invalidated by aforementioned `@Min` constraint:

```java
@Component
final class StringToInteger implements Converter<String, Integer> {

    public Integer convert(String source) {
        try{
            return Integer.valueOf(source);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

}
```

When using with Spring Boot, the `@Component` annotation automatically gets this converter up and running within the entire application context, but what if I want to limit its usage only to a specific `Controller` or even a target request? What is the simplest way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataBinder. You declare it inside your controller.

```
    @InitBinder
    public void customizeBinding (DataBinder binder) {
        DefaultConversionService conversionService = new DefaultConversionService();
        conversionService.addConverter(new StringToInteger());
        binder.setConversionService(conversionService);
    }
```

**EDIT:** you can use a formatter instead.

```
@InitBinder
public void customizeBinding (DataBinder binder) {
    binder.addCustomFormatter(new StringToInteger());
}

class StringToInteger implements Formatter<Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer parse(String s, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        try {
            return Integer.valueOf(s);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String print(Integer i, Locale locale) {
        return Objects.toString(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: It throws `java.lang.IllegalStateException: DataBinder is already initialized with ConversionService`

Comment: Seems, like I can use `@InitBinder` to register custom `Formatter` or `PropertyEditor` for a single Controller, but not a `Converter`. Thank you anyway.

Comment: The formatter will be use to convert the request parameters, path variables or form fields. I think this should work for your usecase. I could set the conversion without error but I made a simple project...